# Excel Connection Manager in SSIS 2005

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2005

Can we cerate Excel Connection Manager that can establish a connection with (.xlsx) file in SSIS 2005 .
I can create a connection manager that makes a connection only to (.xls) file. 
Please let me the know the possiblities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSIS 2005 cannot connect to an XLSX file using the Excel Connection Manager. 
To make SSIS 2005  connect to an XLSX file, you will have to use an OLE DB connection manager instead.

Here is a walk-through. http://dataintegrity.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/xlsx/

And http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2010/03/02/using-excel-2007-in-ssis-2005/